# Test bed application for executing LinQ queries against AdventureWorks

Tags: linq, testing, linq-to-entities, sample

I am looking for a "test bed" application which will help me to learn Linq by writing queries and immediately executing them against the AdventureWorks database.

Why AdventureWorks? Because it is a sample database Microsoft uses in their documentation?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Just use [LINQPad](http://www.linqpad.net/). It can connect to many kinds of database, and will automatically generate a Linq-enabled data context for you. It's free and very easy to use (you can also get auto-completion as a paid option)